# Add a scrollbar to ListView

Tags: android, xml, listview

I want my `ListView` to have a vertical scrollbar, but i cannot figure it out. What I have right now has no effect.

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbarSize="6dp"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false">
</ListView>
```

Comment: `android:fadeScrollbars` should map to `setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false)`, which works for me: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Threads/AsyncTask

Comment: That did not work for me